# can't route successfully between components in react app

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router

I have a static react app (that means there is not server side rendering) located under `example.com/web-class.gr`. My problem is that I can't route between components when I use my sidebar menu.

For instance. When I navigate to `example.com/web-class.gr/css-intermediate` the page loads as expected. From now on if I navigate to different `lessonName` the page is loading as expected. But I also have exercises, which I can't load when I press the corresponding button in my menu. To get an idea this is my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link as ReactLink } from 'react-router';
import sidebarStore from './Sidebar/SidebarStore';
import lessonValues from '../../lessonValues';
import LessonStore from '../../LessonStore';
import SidebarLink from './Sidebar/SidebarLink';


export default class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      SidebarIsCollapse: sidebarStore.getCurrentState()
    }
    this.NavMdPlaceholderClass = 'hidden-xs col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3';
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    sidebarStore.on('change', () => {
      this.setState({ SidebarIsCollapse: sidebarStore.getCurrentState() });
      this.ChangeSidebarState();
    });
    this.RenderMainMenu();
  }

  ChangeSidebarState() {
    const NAV_DefaultClasses = "col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ";
    if (this.state.SidebarIsCollapse) {
      this.NavMdPlaceholderClass = NAV_DefaultClasses + "slideInLeft";
    } else {
      this.NavMdPlaceholderClass = NAV_DefaultClasses + "slideOffLeft";
    }
  }

  RenderMainMenu() {
    this.main_menu = [];
    for (let link of lessonValues) {
      let { Id, url, isExercise, title } = link;
      this.main_menu.push(<SidebarLink key={Id} url={url} isExercise={isExercise} title={title}/>);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class={this.NavMdPlaceholderClass} id="nav-md-placeholder">
        <nav id="sidebar">
          <ul id="main-menu">
            <li class="ripple-btn">
                <ReactLink to="/" onClick={this.SetLessonDetails.bind(this)}>
                  <span class="item-align-fix">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style={{'marginRight': '10px'}}></i>
                    <strong>
                      <span>AΡΧΙΚΗ</span>
                    </strong>
                  </span>
                </ReactLink>
              </li>

              {this.main_menu}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

here is the SidebarLink component file:

```
import React from 'react';
import LessonStore from '../../../LessonStore';
import { Link as ReactLink } from 'react-router';

export default class SidebarLink extends React.Component {
  SetPageTitle() {
    LessonStore.setLesson(this.props.url);
  }

  render() {
    let glyphoconType = 'glyphicon ';
    glyphoconType += this.props.isExercise ? 'glyphicon-pencil' : 'glyphicon-ok-sign';
    glyphoconType += ' nav-ico untaken-lesson';

    return (
      <li class="ripple-btn">
        <ReactLink to={this.props.url} onClick={() => this.SetPageTitle()} >
          <span class="item-align-fix">
            <i class={glyphoconType}></i>
              <span>{this.props.title}</span>
          </span>
        </ReactLink>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

But if I refresh the page manually, I am able to reveal the exercise page. But now I can't navigate to any other element. Only if I click it in sidebar menu and manually refresh the page.

To sum up:

- The lessons are loading dynamically. I can navigate between them.
- I can't navigate to exercises. Only if I click the corresponding exercise and hit the refresh button.
- If I'm viewing an exercise (eg `exercise-1`), I am not able to navigate to any other component.

I use `nginx` and below is my rule for the project:

```
location ^~ /web-class.gr/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /web-class.gr/index.html break;
        }
    }
```

And lastly here is my sidebar component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link as ReactLink } from 'react-router';
import sidebarStore from './Sidebar/SidebarStore';
import lessonValues from '../../lessonValues';
import LessonStore from '../../LessonStore';
import SidebarLink from './Sidebar/SidebarLink';

// some other helper functions here

  render() {
    return (
      <div class={this.NavMdPlaceholderClass} id="nav-md-placeholder">
        <nav id="sidebar">
          <ul id="main-menu">
            <li class="ripple-btn">
                <ReactLink to="/web-class.gr/" onClick={this.SetLessonDetails.bind(this)}>
                  <span class="item-align-fix">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style={{'marginRight': '10px'}}></i>
                    <strong>
                      <span>AΡΧΙΚΗ</span>
                    </strong>
                  </span>
                </ReactLink>
              </li>

              {this.main_menu}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
```

Is there any problem with `ReactLink to`?  **On my `apache` machine all works as expected.** I can't figure out why my program breaks.

### Update

I provide the link of the site to help your job become easier. The site is in greek although I believe you can understand it's structure.

[web-class.gr](https://www.georgegkas.discrete.gr/web-class.gr/)

[Code on Github](https://github.com/GeorgeGkas/web-class.gr)

Comment: You can try few things, In sidebar component, we don't know how your `this.main_menu` looks like.. so uploading all the relevant code/files would be good., And here `<Route path="/web-class.gr/" component={Layout} >` you dont' need to add `/web-class.gr/`, just doing `web-class.gr` would work.

Comment: @RandomUser I updated my code files. please tell me if you need more details.

Comment: Have you inspected the pages after clicking on the links? are there any javascript Errors?

Comment: @DavidNeto no erros.

Comment: @RandomUser I provided the link.

Comment: Wherever you're doing forEach/map loop, add a `key` prop there., ex: `<span key={unique_key}>your route link</span>` Check your code for where you have missed it.

Comment: Also you said when you navigate to `example.com/web-class.gr/css-intermediate` it works, That's wrong, the page just reloads and that's the reason you can see the correct content.. this just means sever is rendering the entire page instead of react.

Comment: Having access to the entire source code would have allowed us test this locally and find exactly which file/component is causing this error.. but hopefully you can fix it now., Just check the console in developer tools for all the errors in the app.

Comment: @RandomUser I'll upload the github link.

Comment: Cloning the repo, will update you soon.

Comment: This was caused by not providing `unique key` for JSX components in `array`. Created a new pull request, Anyways i made changes to the `/react/pages/Lesson.js` File, you can check the updated code here: https://gist.github.com/dhruv-kumar-jha/d75c6e70c017d0e3f6ef6b7c6a8e4594

Comment: @RandomUser and why this worked on my machine? I mean without the unique keys. I tested right now.

Comment: @RandomUser Nope nothing again. It does not work. I updated the file check the link yourself. Thanks for the pull request. We'll talk on github if the bountry expires.

Comment: This is different issue, react router cannot find any matching routes.. checking it now., It might have worked because you didn't have any component which required unique keys or there were always errors and you just didn't see them..

Comment: Its not working, mostly because you're running the app in a subfolder `web-class.gr` instead of project `root`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second Update:

Change your **render** code in `react/index.js` to

```
ReactDom.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory} >
    <Route path="/" component={Layout} >
      <IndexRoute component={Index} ></IndexRoute>
      <Route path="/exercise-1" name="exercise-1" component={Exercise1} ></Route>
      <Route path="/exercise-2" name="exercise-2" component={Exercise2} ></Route>
      <Route path="/exercise-3" name="exercise-3" component={Exercise3} ></Route>
      <Route path="/exercise-4" name="exercise-4" component={Exercise4} ></Route>
      <Route path="/exercise-5" name="exercise-5" component={Exercise5} ></Route>
      <Route path="/exercise-6" name="exercise-6" component={Exercise6} ></Route>
      <Route path="/:lessonName" name="lesson" component={Lesson} ></Route>
      <Route path=":lessonName" name="lesson" component={Lesson} ></Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
,app);
```

i..e the path starts with **`/`**

Comment: Okay you're perfect. This fixed the most of my issues. You can check it yourself. But now I have a last one. Wen I navigate  directly to a lesson or exercise, My react Router component is null (for example if you enter directly to https://www.georgegkas.discrete.gr/web-class.gr/css-novice). Why is this happening ? Moreover I chnage the root path to `/web-class.gr/` beacuse if I use only `/` I get 404 when navigate to index page.

Comment: Where did you change the root path `/web-class.gr/`?. IGNORE.. saw it.

Comment: I give you the bountry points cause you deserve it. Please inform me if you can solve the above issue.

Comment: Will setup nginx and try to mimic this locally and yes solve this., I will update you after solving it.

Comment: @GeorgeGkas one hacky way to fix this is just add this route at the end `<Route path=":lessonName" name="lesson" component={Lesson} ></Route>`..  I have updated the answer. As soon as i find the real reason for this issue i will update you.., Since you're using react app in a `sub directory` it might cause this issue.. also `nginx` config might be causing this as well.

Answer (score 1):

**This One worked For me**

> NB

for **React Router**

use `<BrowserRouter>` tag only once to enclose the whole of your application.

Use this tag at the point of Rendering.

> For Example

If you are using `Create-React-app` .Use this at your `Index.js` file

`ReactDom.Render(<BrowserRouter><App/></BrowserRouter>)`